# How to get glucose meter data in flutter BLE using flutter_blue

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to flutter ble. I am trying to read from Accu-check the last glucose
test details.

This is what I get for the UUID 00002a51-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[32, 2]

This is what I get for the UUID 00002a08-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[228, 7, 9, 17, 14, 30, 0]

How do I convert it into human readable form ?

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The official adopted UUIDs are in the range: `0000xxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB`

You can find the names of Bluetooth SIG adopted UUIDs at: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/characteristics/

Once you have the name then you can look up the structure of the data by replacing the name in the URL below:

https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.glucose_measurement.xml

These XML files should give you the information you need to covert those byte arrays into human readable information.

Couple of similar questions that may help:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63648034/7721752
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63340809/7721752